# Appletviewer character encoding wrong after ubuntu update

Tags: encoding

I ran the most recent batch of updates to ubuntu 12.04 and, after this, appletviewer started to fail to show chinese characters even with the JVM file encoding arg set to UTF-8. Before everything was fine, and nothing else has changed in my setup apart from the updates. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

=====RESOLVED======
The problem was not the encoding but the Java Font instance I had used for the Chinese. For some reason, this had started causing display problems at the same time as the updates ran, whereas before it was fine. It seems unlikely they were connected, but who knows...

Comment: You can post the edit as an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that initially, but it said I had to wait a few hours because my reputation is too low...